# Boolean Algebra Simplification Unknown Step Introduce Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I've been trying to interpret a logical proposition for several days. I need to simplify, I can't do it with the laws that I know, but using online tools I can find the result, but in the step by step a method appears that I don't know

The question is:
In the next table what does it mean: "introduce Variables"  **(I know the other laws)**

where does **(A+A’)** come from

the proposition is:
**[(A’B’) + (A’+C)’]’ (B’C’)’**

The Solution is:

| [(A’B’)+(A’+C)’]’ (B’C’)’ | Defininition |
| --- | --- |
| (A+B)(A’+C’’)(B’C’)’ | De morgan Law |
| (AA’ + AC + BA’ + BC) (B’C’)’ | Distrib Law |
| (0 + AC + BA’ + BC) (B’C’)’ | Complement Law |
| (AC + BA’ + BC) (B’C’)’ | Identity Law |
| (AC + BA’ + BC) (B’’+C’’) | De morgan Law |
| ACB + ACC +BA’B + BA’C + BCB + BCC | Distrib Law |
| ACB + CA + BA’B + BA’C + BCB + BCC | Idemp Law |
| AC + BA’B + BA’C + BCB + BCC | Absorpt Law |
| AC + BA’ + BA’C + BCB + BCC | Idemp Law |
| BA’ + AC + BCB + BCC | Absorpt Law |
| BC + BA’ + AC | Idemp Law |
| BC (**A+A’**) + BA’ + AC | **Introduce Variables** |
| BCA + BCA’ + BA’ + AC | Distrib Law |
| AC + BA’ | Absorpt Law |
| AC + BA’ | Answer |

Note: Other sites call this step: Consensus

Thanks a lot, my head is going to explode, I can't find anything on the internet to guide me.

Comment: I suppose you know that $A+A'=1$, and that $X1=X$, for all $X$. So $BC=BC(A+A')$.

Comment: Hi  @amrsa, first of all thanks for your quick response, i understand what you mention, but why does it apply only to BC and not to the others? is it for convenience? I have to explain the step by step of why things happen, and I don't know how to explain it, starting because I don't even know what to call it, can i justify this step as "algebraic manipulation"??. Tanks for the help and patience

Comment: What is called the [Consensus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem) is not that identity alone, but $$BC+BA'+AC=AC+BA'.$$ What you have in those steps is its proof (for this particular case). That was the chosen step because it was convenient, yes! So it's a form of algebraic manipulation but it was done with some insight. Probably whoever did it knew about the theorem.

Comment: @amrsa, thanks a lot, that's the answer that i needed, I can manipulate the equation to convenience as long as it does not affect its values